# Laravel 4 DB transactions not committing and rollbacking

Tags: php, database, laravel, laravel-4, transactions

I am using laravel 4 and trying to use **commit and rollback functions**. But functions are not working for me.

I am following laravel documentations (https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/database#database-transactions) but still its not working.

Here is my code :

```
DB::transaction(function() use ($product)
 {
     DB::table('products')->insert($product);           
     DB::rollBack();
 });
```

Its creating new entry in products table. which is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

In your example, the transaction will only be rolled back when there is an exception.

> Note: Any exception thrown within the transaction closure will cause the transaction to be rolled back automatically.

You have to manually start your transaction with `DB::beginTransaction()` and end it with `DB::rollback()` or `DB::commit()`

It is also possible to do this within a try catch statement.

```
try {
    DB::beginTransaction();

    // Do something

    DB::commit();
} catch (\Exception $e) {
    DB::rollback();
    throw $e;
}
```